# How to solve " multiclass format is not supported" error in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from sklearn import preprocessing

df_train = pd.read_csv('Iris_train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('Iris_test.csv')

X_train = df_train.drop(['TYPE'],axis=1).values
y_train = df_train_fixed[['TYPE']].values
X_test = df_test.values
from sklearn import preprocessing
std_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
std_scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_std_sk = std_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_std_sk = std_scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', 
                            solver='saga', 
                            multi_class='ovr')
logreg.fit(X_train_std_sk,y_train.ravel() )
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_std_sk)
y_pred

y_real = pd.read_csv('Iris_test_labels.csv').values
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_real,y_pred)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_real,y_pred)
y_prob=logreg.predict_proba(X_test_std_sk)
y_score=logreg.predict_proba(X_test_std_sk)[:,1]
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
y_real
fpr,tpr,thresholds=roc_curve(y_real, y_score)
```

after this code then error come. I don't know why. The detailed error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-2d9f99ac1496> in <module>
----> 1 fpr,tpr,thresholds=roc_curve(y_real, y_score)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    769     """
    770     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
--> 771         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    772 
    773     # Attempt to drop thresholds corresponding to points in between and

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    534     if not (y_type == "binary" or
    535             (y_type == "multiclass" and pos_label is not None)):
--> 536         raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    537 
    538     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

That is I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Iris is a 3-class dataset, while according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) for `roc_curve`:

> this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task.

So, you cannot use it here, which is essentially what the error message says.

For multiclass classification (like iris data), [`roc_auc_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) offers an alternative:

> this implementation can be used with binary, multiclass and multilabel classification, but some restrictions apply (see Parameters).

although only for the AUC score, not the FPR & TPR rates (in multiclass classification, the very notions of false positives, true negatives etc are not exactly straightforward and not particularly useful).